# If a heat stack goes into FAILED status, any solution to resume?

Tags: openstack

If a heat stack goes into FAILED status(it may be caused by "heat stack create" or "heat stack update"), is there any way to resume(continue from the failure step)?
The only solution I know is to delete the whole heat stack, and recreate again.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If a Heat stack goes into a FAILED status, there are a few steps you can take to try and resume or troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Check the Error Message**: Examine the error message associated with the stack failure. The error message will provide valuable information about what caused the failure, which is crucial for resolving the issue.
2. **Review the Template**: Verify the Heat template used to create the stack. Ensure that the template is valid, and there are no syntax errors or resource conflicts.
3. **Check Resource Dependencies**: Analyze the resources defined in the template to ensure they don't have any unresolved dependencies. Make sure that all required resources are properly defined and available.
4. **Inspect Resource Configuration**: Examine the configuration of each resource to ensure there are no misconfigurations or incorrect parameter values.
5. **Review Heat Engine Logs**: Check the logs of the Heat Engine, where more detailed error messages and stack creation steps are recorded. These logs can provide insights into what went wrong.
6. **Resource Availability**: Verify if there are sufficient resources (e.g., compute, storage) available in your cloud environment to create the stack.
7. **Retry the Stack**: If the failure was due to a transient issue or resource unavailability, you can retry the stack creation process. Use the "openstack stack create" command or your preferred method to recreate the stack.
8. **Implement Rollback**: Make sure the Heat stack is set up to perform a rollback in case of failures. A rollback will revert any changes made during the stack creation process, reducing potential issues.
9. **Update Heat Templates**: If the failure is due to a template issue, update the template to address the problem and try creating the stack again.
10. **Reach Out to Support**: If you are using a cloud provider's service, consider reaching out to their support team for assistance. They may have insights into the specific issue you're facing.

Remember to take appropriate precautions before attempting any changes to avoid any accidental data loss or disruption to existing resources. It's also a good practice to test your Heat templates in a non-production environment to catch any potential issues before deploying to a live environment.

Comment: My question is:
Is there a OpenStack command can "resume" a heat stack in FAILED status instead of fix issue, and recreate the heat stack?

BTW, please don't use a generative AI to provide the answer!